# WAF Modsecurity CRS rule not deduct HTML tags

Tags: html, nginx, owasp, mod-security

we have used modsecurity nginx owasp coreruleset-3.3 in our nginx webserver. Below are the input from web ui.

```
1. {
  "data": {
    "id": 1002,
    "email": "testmodsec@gmail.com",    
    "name": "ske<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\"js\")'>test</h1>",
    "locale": "en",
    "category": 1,
    "status": 0,
  }
}

2. {
  "data": {
    "id": 1002,
    "email": "testmodsec@gmail.com",    
    "name": "ske<img src=''onerror='alert(1)'>",
    "locale": "en",
    "category": 1,
    "status": 0,
  }
}

3. {
  "data": {
    "id": 1002,
    "email": "testmodsec@gmail.com",    
    "name": "ske<h1>test</h1>",
    "locale": "en",
    "category": 1,
    "status": 0,
  }
}
```

Input 1 & 2 triggered by HTML Injection crs rule-941, but for input 3 crs rule-941320 HTML Tag handler not triggered.

We need to block all 3 inputs by modsec crs rules.

Used coreruleset version v3.3

please help

Answer (score 0):

I̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶n̶k̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶t̶y̶p̶i̶c̶a̶l̶ ̶e̶x̶a̶m̶p̶l̶e̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶ ̶p̶o̶s̶i̶t̶i̶v̶e̶ ̶m̶a̶t̶c̶h̶ ̶(̶F̶P̶)̶.̶ ̶T̶h̶e̶ ̶s̶o̶l̶u̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶m̶a̶k̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶c̶u̶s̶t̶o̶m̶ ̶e̶x̶c̶l̶u̶s̶i̶o̶n̶.

Edit: (sorry, that was my mistake...)

But unfortunately I can't reproduce your issue. I tested all requests above (1, 2 and 3) both with Apache+mod_security2 and Nginx+libmodsecurity3, but rule 941320 was triggered in all cases.

See log lines from Apache and Nginx (especially the `[data]` field value).

```
ModSecurity: Warning. Pattern match "<(?:a|abbr|acronym|address|applet|area|audioscope|b|base|basefront|bdo|bgsound|big|blackface|blink|blockquote|body|bq|br|button|caption|center|cite|code|col|colgroup|comment|dd|del|dfn|dir|div|dl|dt|em|embed|fieldset|fn|font|form|frame|frameset|h1|head ..." at ARGS:data.name. [file "/home/airween/src/coreruleset/rules/REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS.conf"] [line "784"] [id "941320"] [msg "Possible XSS Attack Detected - HTML Tag Handler"] [data "Matched Data: <h1> found within ARGS:data.name: ske<h1>test</h1>"]
```

```
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `<(?:a|abbr|acronym|address|applet|area|audioscope|b|base|basefront|bdo|bgsound|big|blackface|blink|blockquote|body|bq|br|button|caption|center|cite|code|col|colgroup|comment|dd|del|dfn|dir|div|dl|dt|e (452 characters omitted)' against variable `ARGS:json.data.name' (Value: `ske<h1>test</h1>' ) [file "/home/airween/src/coreruleset/rules/REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS.conf"] [line "765"] [id "941320"] [rev ""] [msg "Possible XSS Attack Detected - HTML Tag Handler"] [data "Matched Data: <h1> found within ARGS:json.data.name: ske<h1>test</h1>"]
```

Please note, that the JSON requests above are wrong: the `,` after the field `"status": 0,` is not necessary. But may be that's just a typo.

Comment: Actually I needs 941320 rule to trigger and block it for input 3, by default its not triggering this rule.. Tried with above conf changes still not triggering

Comment: There is a lot more input values, so just removed last few fields.

Comment: I used this manual steps to install modsecurity-nginx -https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/securing-nginx-with-modsecurity/, for input 1 and 2 triggered by HTML Injection (941160) rule and centos nginx running inside k8s pod container.

Comment: Wait, now you mentioned the rule 941160, but in the OP you did the 941320. I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Btw, could you open an issue on CRS's Github page? https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/issues. Please fill the template carefully, and if it possible, attach a curl example with helps us to investigate the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, Input 1 & 2 triggered by crs rule 941160 but for input 3, i could see crs rules there html handler rule (941320) is matching.

Comment: ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `(?i:(?:<\w[\s\S]*[\s\/]|['\"](?:[\s\S]*[\s\/])?)(?:on(?:d(?:e(?:vice(?:(?:orienta|mo)tion|proximity|found|light)|livery(?:success|error)|activate)|r(?:ag(?:e(?:n(?:ter|d)|xit)|(?:gestur|leav)e|start|d (3146 characters omitted)' against variable `ARGS:json.jobTitle' (Value: `skeske<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\"js\")'>test</h1>' ) [file "/usr/local/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS.conf"] [line "181"] [id "941160"] [rev ""] [msg "NoScript XSS InjectionChecker: HTML Injection"]

Comment: please help on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76060677/waf-modsecurity-audit-logs-how-to-identify-suspicious-requests-in-detectiononl

Comment: @sk2 - seems that azurit helps you.