# WAF Modsecurity audit logs - how to identify suspicious requests in DetectionOnly mode

Tags: nginx, owasp, mod-security, web-application-firewall

We have enabled modsecurity in our nginx, modsecurity configured "SecRuleEngine DetectionOnly" for wihtout blocking any requests to identify suspicious requests that blocked by actual requests. But we couldn't identify requests in audit log which is suspicious that will actualy blocked by modsec. The logs are looks same kind of messges.

Difference i could see in "SecRuleEngine On" audit log message following like this - "ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). " but "DetectionOnly" not seeing these kind of messages.

please help us to identify blocking requests in DetectionOnly mode.

Comment: Can you show some of the audit log messages when modsec is enabled?

Comment: SecAuditLogParts ABIJDEFHZ- These are the log parts enabled.
With SecRuleEngine On, I could see below messages in end of part H "ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). " with DetectionOnly mode these message also not there, could see only difference from all the parts of log

Comment: Please provide few full records from audit log, not only text of error message, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

azurit - due to log is huge, shared few transactions log only

```
---YiCoIdi5---A--
[25/Apr/2023:13:32:50 +0000] 168242957010.649244 195.90.110.113 3929 10.201.137.72 443
---YiCoIdi5---B--
GET /web/assoc HTTP/1.1
Host: myapp.com
myapp.com: 443:54.160.98.23
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

---YiCoIdi5---D--

---YiCoIdi5---F--
HTTP/1.1 401
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' myapp.com *.myapp.com;
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Expires: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Tue, 25 Apr 2023 13:32:50 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Server: nginx
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

---YiCoIdi5---H--

---YiCoIdi5---I--

---YiCoIdi5---J--


---YiCoIdi5---J--

---YiCoIdi5---Z--

---vYk8BERa---A--
[25/Apr/2023:13:32:50 +0000] 168242957014.381922 134.141.2.72 11127 10.201.137.72 443
---vYk8BERa---B--
GET /web/assoc HTTP/1.1
Host: myapp.com
myapp.com: 443:54.160.98.23
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

---vYk8BERa---D--

---vYk8BERa---F--
HTTP/1.1 401
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' myapp.com *.myapp.com;
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Expires: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Tue, 25 Apr 2023 13:32:50 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Server: nginx
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

---vYk8BERa---H--

---vYk8BERa---I--

---vYk8BERa---J--

---vYk8BERa---Z--

---Rl5gNaor---A--
[26/Apr/2023:06:04:53 +0000] 168248909380.738105 157.51.193.211 57776 10.201.137.72 443
---Rl5gNaor---B--
PUT /user/info?ownerId=1244322242&ownerIds=22242w HTTP/2.0
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
content-type: application/json
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
origin: https://myapp.com
accept: application/json
x-csrf-token: f4d55b7b-7e0f-47ce-bd00-44bcd78f4bfd
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="112", "Google Chrome";v="112", "Not:A-Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
referer: https://myapp.com
content-length: 356
host: myapp.com
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
cookie: _ga=GA1.2.925851077.1649323497; intercom-device-id-dqesl6bn=1375a2ec-f1c4-49d2-b355-6e4c5dc72294; api_access_token=eyJraWQiOiI1YjE4N2UzNzg0MDI0Nzg1YWM2ZmJjOTY0M2M0YjU3NiIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiJzYXJqdW5hbkBleHRyZW1lY2xvdWRpcS5jb20iLCJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxMzE0MjA4Miwicm9sZSI6IkFkbWluaXN0cmF0b3IiLCJjdXN0b21lcl9pZCI6MTMxNDE3MzIsImN1c3RvbWVyX21vZGUiOjAsImhpcV9lbmFibGVkIjpmYWxzZSwib3duZXJfaWQiOjQ4MDkyLCJvcmdfaWQiOjAsImRhdGFfY2VudGVyIjoiRzJSMSIsInNoYXJkIjoiRVUiLCJxdW90YSI6Ijc1MDA7dz0zNjAwIiwianRpIjoiNGI5NGFmZjNhYjFjNDExMjlhZTA2MmQ1OWNjMGZlZmQiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2cyLWV1MC5xYS54Y2xvdWRpcS5jb20iLCJpYXQiOjE2ODI0ODg3NzksImV4cCI6MTY4MjU3NTE3OX0.OGwNmemqwjCnFEaKljfqktIMltpZCJSTrSSPw9M-AVke-TLL69AG2V_EsVSm9-A6hLwBPFeoH0aSaA_3TvgO2zDL1Rm36WjsPDWTZ3iMzyVyxPDs3maC37SLxJqqA_5wAFDbHQmuuSmXpvG6C2BuQHBB8OEvLs18GkVwxFOb16OwgEiTGvrItjON3w5P-IBsdx6Bziza8yVrFOalLHHIc5NCybm5XH7IHE4R7kKQnuMkA9YW0QUjUxZGPiHs8HMHgZhQotXfxl498SObRbre5abIUeohAivEXbaPDCWuuHnnaxrTFUBh2Rn3BbpZ701HH-1uuLdYmo0B9Tp4LS5KAQ; oauth2AccessToken=O/c877UBtE7NCe8BLSDV+C2coYvvH8/EiR7UbWc7M2S4HqSoZqMtBt2jlvGvkHJQ#1682489039603#1800000#a14964ce00fa72dee1322f022296bec2
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9

---Rl5gNaor---D--

---Rl5gNaor---F--
HTTP/2.0 200
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' myapp.com *.myapp.com;
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self' data: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' myapp.com *.myapp.com;
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Server: nginx
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Wed, 26 Apr 2023 06:04:53 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range
Set-Cookie: oauth2AccessToken=O/c877UBtE7NCe8BLSDV+C2coYvvH8/EiR7UbWc7M2S4HqSoZqMtBt2jlvGvkHJQ#1682489093577#1800000#8af70ed6928df725aeec9ac5c30139eb; Domain=.yourapp.com; Path=/; Version=0; Secure; HttpOnly
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block


---Rl5gNaor---H--
ModSecurity: Warning. detected XSS using libinjection. [file "/usr/local/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS.conf"] [line "38"] [id "941100"] [rev ""] [msg "XSS Attack Detected via libinjection"] [data "Matched Data: XSS data found within ARGS:json.jobname: Job1com<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\x22JS Running1\x22)'>test</h1>\x22"] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.4"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-xss"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/152/242"] [hostname "10.201.137.72"] [uri "/services/acct/entry/user/info"] [unique_id "168248909380.738105"] [ref "v14,64t:utf8toUnicode,t:urlDecodeUni,t:htmlEntityDecode,t:jsDecode,t:cssDecode,t:removeNulls"]
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `(?i)[\s\"'`;\/0-9=\x0B\x09\x0C\x3B\x2C\x28\x3B]on[a-zA-Z]+[\s\x0B\x09\x0C\x3B\x2C\x28\x3B]*?=' against variable `ARGS:json.jobname' (Value: `Job1com<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\"TestRun\")'>test</h1>"' ) [file "/usr/local/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS.conf"] [line "90"] [id "941120"] [rev ""] [msg "XSS Filter - Category 2: Event Handler Vector"] [data "Matched Data:  onmouseover= found within ARGS:json.jobname: Job1com<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\x22TestRun\x22)'>test</h1>\x22"] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.4"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-xss"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/152/242"] [hostname "10.201.137.72"] [uri "/user/info"] [unique_id "168248909380.738105"] [ref "o10,13v14,64t:utf8toUnicode,t:urlDecodeUni,t:htmlEntityDecode,t:jsDecode,t:cssDecode,t:removeNulls"]
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `(?i:(?:<\w[\s\S]*[\s\/]|['\"](?:[\s\S]*[\s\/])?)(?:on(?:d(?:e(?:vice(?:(?:orienta|mo)tion|proximity|found|light)|livery(?:success|error)|activate)|r(?:ag(?:e(?:n(?:ter|d)|xit)|(?:gestur|leav)e|start|d (3146 characters omitted)' against variable `ARGS:json.jobname' (Value: `Job1com<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\"TestRun\")'>test</h1>"' ) [file "/usr/local/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS.conf"] [line "181"] [id "941160"] [rev ""] [msg "NoScript XSS InjectionChecker: HTML Injection"] [data "Matched Data: <h1 onmouseover= found within ARGS:json.jobname: Job1com<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\x22TestRun\x22)'>test</h1>\x22"] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.4"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-xss"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/152/242"] [hostname "10.201.137.72"] [uri "/user/info"] [unique_id "168248909380.738105"] [ref "o7,16v14,64t:utf8toUnicode,t:urlDecodeUni,t:htmlEntityDecode,t:jsDecode,t:cssDecode,t:removeNulls"]
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `<(?:a|abbr|acronym|address|applet|area|audioscope|b|base|basefront|bdo|bgsound|big|blackface|blink|blockquote|body|bq|br|button|caption|center|cite|code|col|colgroup|comment|dd|del|dfn|dir|div|dl|dt|e (452 characters omitted)' against variable `ARGS:json.jobname' (Value: `Job1com<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\"TestRun\")'>test</h1>"' ) [file "/usr/local/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-941-APPLICATION-ATTACK-XSS.conf"] [line "765"] [id "941320"] [rev ""] [msg "Possible XSS Attack Detected - HTML Tag Handler"] [data "Matched Data: <h1  found within ARGS:json.jobname: job1com<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\x22TestRun\x22)'>test</h1>\x22"] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.4"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-xss"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/152/242/63"] [tag "PCI/6.5.1"] [tag "paranoia-level/2"] [hostname "10.201.137.72"] [uri "/user/info"] [unique_id "168248909380.738105"] [ref "o7,4v14,64t:urlDecodeUni,t:jsDecode,t:lowercase,t:htmlEntityDecode"]
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `(?:^\s*[\"'`;]+|[\"'`]+\s*$)' against variable `ARGS:json.jobname' (Value: `Job1com<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\"TestRun\")'>test</h1>"' ) [file "/usr/local/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI.conf"] [line "500"] [id "942110"] [rev ""] [msg "SQL Injection Attack: Common Injection Testing Detected"] [data "Matched Data: \x22 found within ARGS:json.jobname: Job1com<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\x5c\x22TestRun\x5c\x22)'>test</h1>\x22"] [severity "4"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.4"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-sqli"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/152/248/66"] [tag "PCI/6.5.2"] [tag "paranoia-level/2"] [hostname "10.201.137.72"] [uri "/user/info"] [unique_id "168248909380.738105"] [ref "o63,1v14,64t:utf8toUnicode,t:urlDecodeUni"]
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `(?i:[\s'\"`()]*?\b([\d\w]+)\b[\s'\"`()]*?(?:<(?:=(?:[\s'\"`()]*?(?!\b\1\b)[\d\w]+|>[\s'\"`()]*?(?:\b\1\b))|>?[\s'\"`()]*?(?!\b\1\b)[\d\w]+)|(?:not\s+(?:regexp|like)|is\s+not|>=?|!=|\^)[\s'\"`()]*?(?!\ (78 characters omitted)' against variable `ARGS:json.jobname' (Value: `Job1com<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\"TestRun\")'>test</h1>"' ) [file "/usr/local/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI.conf"] [line "571"] [id "942130"] [rev ""] [msg "SQL Injection Attack: SQL Tautology Detected"] [data "Matched Data: Job1com<h1 found within ARGS:json.jobname: Job1com<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\x5c\x22TestRun\x5c\x22)'>test</h1>\x22"] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.4"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [hostname "10.201.137.72"] [uri "/user/info"] [unique_id "168248909380.738105"] [ref "o0,10o0,7v14,64"]
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `(?i)\b(?:c(?:o(?:n(?:v(?:ert(?:_tz)?)?|cat(?:_ws)?|nection_id)|(?:mpres)?s|ercibility|(?:un)?t|llation|alesce)|ur(?:rent_(?:time(?:stamp)?|date|user)|(?:dat|tim)e)|h(?:ar(?:(?:acter)?_length|set)?|r)| (1684 characters omitted)' against variable `ARGS:json.jobname' (Value: `Job1com<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\"TestRun\")'>test</h1>"' ) [file "/usr/local/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI.conf"] [line "609"] [id "942150"] [rev ""] [msg "SQL Injection Attack"] [data "Matched Data: log( found within ARGS:json.jobname: job1com<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\x5c\x22TestRun\x5c\x22)'>test</h1>\x22"] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.4"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-sqli"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/152/248/66"] [tag "PCI/6.5.2"] [tag "paranoia-level/2"] [hostname "10.201.137.72"] [uri "/user/info"] [unique_id "168248909380.738105"] [ref "o32,4v14,64t:urlDecodeUni,t:lowercase"]
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `(?i:[\"'`]\s*?(?:(?:n(?:and|ot)|(?:x?x)?or|between|\|\||and|div|&&)\s+[\s\w]+=\s*?\w+\s*?having\s+|like(?:\s+[\s\w]+=\s*?\w+\s*?having\s+|\W*?[\"'`\d])|[^?\w\s=.,;)(]++\s*?[(@\"'`]*?\s*?\w+\W+\w|\*\s* (166 characters omitted)' against variable `ARGS:json.jobname' (Value: `Job1com<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\"TestRun\")'>test</h1>"' ) [file "/usr/local/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI.conf"] [line "732"] [id "942260"] [rev ""] [msg "Detects basic SQL authentication bypass attempts 2/3"] [data "Matched Data: '>test</h found within ARGS:json.jobname: Job1com<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\x5c\x22TestRun\x5c\x22)'>test</h1>\x22"] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.4"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-sqli"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/152/248/66"] [tag "PCI/6.5.2"] [tag "paranoia-level/2"] [hostname "10.201.137.72"] [uri "/user/info"] [unique_id "168248909380.738105"] [ref "o52,9v14,64t:urlDecodeUni"]
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `(?i:\b(?:c(?:o(?:n(?:v(?:ert(?:_tz)?)?|cat(?:_ws)?|nection_id)|(?:mpres)?s|ercibility|(?:un)?t|alesce)|ur(?:rent_(?:time(?:stamp)?|date|user)|(?:dat|tim)e)|h(?:ar(?:(?:acter)?_length|set)?|r)|iel(?:in (1704 characters omitted)' against variable `ARGS:json.jobname' (Value: `Job1com<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\"TestRun\")'>test</h1>"' ) [file "/usr/local/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI.conf"] [line "1037"] [id "942410"] [rev ""] [msg "SQL Injection Attack"] [data "Matched Data: log( found within ARGS:json.jobname: Job1com<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\x5c\x22TestRun\x5c\x22)'>test</h1>\x22"] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.4"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-sqli"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/152/248/66"] [tag "PCI/6.5.2"] [tag "paranoia-level/2"] [hostname "10.201.137.72"] [uri "/user/info"] [unique_id "168248909380.738105"] [ref "o32,4v14,64t:urlDecodeUni"]
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Rx' with parameter `((?:[~!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)\-\+=\{\}\[\]\|:;\"'\xc2\xb4\xe2\x80\x99\xe2\x80\x98`<>][^~!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)\-\+=\{\}\[\]\|:;\"'\xc2\xb4\xe2\x80\x99\xe2\x80\x98`<>]*?){12})' against variable `ARGS:json.jobname' (Value: `Job1com<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\"TestRun\")'>test</h1>"' ) [file "/usr/local/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-942-APPLICATION-ATTACK-SQLI.conf"] [line "1145"] [id "942430"] [rev ""] [msg "Restricted SQL Character Anomaly Detection (args): # of special characters exceeded (12)"] [data "Matched Data: <h1 onmouseover='console.log(\x5c\x22TestRun\x5c\x22)'>test</h1>\x22 found within ARGS:json.jobname: Job1com<h1 onmouseover='console.log(\x5c\x22TestRun\x5c\x22)'>test</h1>\x22"] [severity "4"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.4"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-sqli"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/152/248/66"] [tag "PCI/6.5.2"] [tag "paranoia-level/2"] [hostname "10.201.137.72"] [uri "/user/info"] [unique_id "168248909380.738105"] [ref "o7,57o7,57v14,64t:urlDecodeUni"]
ModSecurity: Warning. Matched "Operator `Ge' with parameter `5' against variable `TX:ANOMALY_SCORE' (Value: `46' ) [file "/usr/local/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-949-BLOCKING-EVALUATION.conf"] [line "81"] [id "949110"] [rev ""] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 46)"] [data ""] [severity "2"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.4"] [maturity "0"] [accuracy "0"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-generic"] [hostname "10.201.137.72"] [uri "/user/info"] [unique_id "168248909380.738105"] [ref ""]

---Rl5gNaor---I--

---Rl5gNaor---J--

---Rl5gNaor---Z--
```